# Taking count from multiple tables using left join

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I am using the following query to get the count from multiple tables:-

```
SELECT 
  b.sales_title,
  c.cat_name,
  count(b.sales_id) as cnt,
  count(e.comment_id) as coun  
FROM tb_sale_report a 
  inner join tbl_sales    b on a.sales_id=b.sales_id 
  inner join  tb_category c on c.cat_id=b.category_id 
  left  join tb_comment   e on b.sales_id=e.sales_id
GROUP BY b.sales_title
```

I am trying to achieve

```
sales_title |   cat_name    |   cnt  |  coun
--------------------------------------------------
Affiliate   |   Kids toys   |   8    |  0
Date Check  |   Handbags    |   26   |  1
Date Date   |   My Category |   4    |  1
Future Date |   Handbags    |   3    |  0
Giovanni    |   Kids toys   |   4    |  1
```

But instead of that i am getting the wrong count, the values for the column `coun` is getting wrong like this,

```
sales_title  |  cat_name    |   cnt  |  coun
---------------------------------------------
Affiliate    |  Kids toys   |   8    |  0
Date Check   |  Handbags    |   26   |  26
Date Date    |  My Category |   4    |  4
Future Date  |  Handbags    |   3    |  0
Giovanni     |  Kids toys   |   4    |  4
```

How can i write the query to achieve my goal.Need help, i am a newbie to programming.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell unless you tell us your table structure/give a small snippet of data that replicates your problem. It looks like your comments table  is being replicated in order to perform the join to the `tbl_sales` table, and so there are duplicates in the count.

Try `COUNT(DISTINCT e.comment_id) as coun` to eliminate this problem.